# Web3 - Total Suppy

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Just wondering if there is a way to calculate the total supply via web3? I imagine you'd need to scan for all addresses? Not sure where to start with coding this one....

EDIT:

So since it's not possible via web3, would be possible via NodeJS or PHP? if so how?

Comment: Total supply of what???

Comment: Sorry haha should have been more specific, I'd like to calculate the total supply of Ether.

Comment: It'd probably (literally) take until the end of time using an RPC-bound service like web3. Just use an API instead? http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethsupply

Comment: That's unfortunate... I've been working on a decentralized API for stats using IPFS & multiple RPC nodes for data collection this was the last piece of the puzzle. Anyway thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: If you're running your own node then the other option would be to read the chain state data directly (rather than via RPC). This would be much faster, but probably much more technically involved. (See this question, for example: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25620/how-to-access-geths-state-trie)

Comment: Or something like QuickBlocks? https://quickblocks.io (I haven't looked at it for a while, so might not be suitable.)